# I am deploying a .Net 4.8 application using githubaction to appservice.But browser shows "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Tags: .net, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

Here is my github action workflow.

`name: Deploy to Development Environment
on:
push:
branches:
- master
pull_request:
branches:
- PrepRod
env:

AZURE_DEVWEBAPP_NAME: GitAc-Dev
AZURE_PREPRODWEBAPP_NAME: GitAc-PreProd
AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: 'D:\a\NewGitAcTest\NewGitAcTest\bin'
jobs:
Build:
runs-on: windows-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2

```
- name: Setup MSBuild
  uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1

- name: Setup NuGet
  uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5

- name: Restore NuGet packages
  run: nuget restore NewGitAcTest.sln

- name: build
  run: |
       msbuild NewGitActest.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /verbosity:minimal
- name: publish
  run: |
       msbuild NewGitActest.sln /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:PublishDir="./artifacts"
  
- name: Upload artifacts
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
        name: myapp
        path: ${{env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH}}
```

DeployDev:
name: Dev
needs: Build
runs-on: windows-latest

```
  environment:
      name: Dev
  steps:
   - name: Download artifacts
     uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
     with:
      name: myapp
      path: artifacts/

   - name: Deploy
     uses: Azure/webapps-deploy@v2
     with:
        app-name: ${{env.AZURE_DEVWEBAPP_NAME}}
        publish-profile: ${{secrets.AZURE_DEVPUBLISH_PROFILE}}
        package: artifacts/`
```

Do I need to unzip my artifacts and then deploy or any suggestion, but in core it is working fine;

Comment: Please share your GitHub Repo.

Comment: Thanks Harshitha ,  https://github.com/jimmyraja000/NewGitAcTest